# Looking for some UI thread and working thread tutorials

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, user-interface

My working environment is VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5. I want to learn the differences between UI thread and worker thread, and any other types of thread (i.e. non-UI thread is the same as worker thread)? I also want to learn the restrictions of what we can do on each type of threads and best practices to avoid any issues.

Appreciate any good tutorials! :-)

Answer (score 2):

There's a long, detailed [tutorial on threading here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/).

Specifically, I'd recommend [this section on worker and UI threads](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml) and how they can interact (it does assume you've read the previous chapters though).

Answer (score 1):

This [site](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) has great threading details covering: Getting Started, Basic Synchronization, Using Threads, and Advanced Topics.

Comment: I know this site, but I did not find related sections which covers differences between UI thread and worker thread.

Comment: From the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(VS.71).aspx Threading Tutorial, it says: "A process can have a user interface thread that manages interactions with the user and worker threads that perform other tasks while the user interface thread waits for user input".  What other differences are you looking for?