# Multithreading: C# program running C dll - Unresponsive C#

Tags: c#, c, multithreading, dll, ui-thread

I wrote a C dll that performs two tasks:

1) Relay certain messages to the C# program

2) Perform an intensive task on a different thread

It all works but the C# UI is unresponsive, even though C is running the intensive task on a different thread.

I have also exposed the C function that kicks off the intensive task to C#, allowing C# to attempt to run that function on a different thread.

No matter what, C# gets bogged down and the C# program becomes unresponsive when the intensive task runs.

I forgot to mention that I have written the entire program in C and it works without a problem but I'd like to write a C# library to use this in future .NET projects.

```
[DllImport(@"C:\projects\math\randomout\Debug\randout.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "task_ToggleTask")]
internal static extern bool task_ToggleTask();

__declspec( dllexport ) BOOL task_ToggleTask()
{
    if ( _threadStopped )
    {
        _threadStopped = FALSE;
        _t_TaskHandle = ( HANDLE )_beginthread( task_Calculate, 0, NULL );
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        _threadStopped = TRUE;
        CloseHandle( _t_TaskHandle );
        return FALSE;
    }
}

static void task_Calculate( void* params )
{

    while ( !_threadStopped )
    {

        WORD nextRestInterval = rand_GetBetween( 15, 50 );

        /*
            trivial math calculations here...
         */

        //next update is at a random interval > 0ms
        Sleep( nextRestInterval );

    }

    _endthread();

}
```

Comment: By unresponsive, do you mean sluggish or no response at all?

Comment: Please show us the code that is invoking the task.

Comment: I don't supposed there's any code involved, is there?

Comment: Some code might be useful, show us how C# is calling the function at least.

Comment: Even if it does the work on a different thread, is the current thread blocked until the other thread is complete?

Comment: We will need some code samples and probably more detail to answer your question. EDIT - lol, went from no comments to six in the space of 30 seconds.

Comment: Can you show us the code you use for calling the native DLL?

Comment: It might be useful to see the C# client code that calls the C dll and the C code that spawns the thread(s).

Comment: We need to see some code on how the C program is called; background worker, thread start, etc.  Also, what is the CPU usage?  If the C program is running at 100% then everything would bog down.  Hard to tell as there is not enough details provided.

Comment: Are you sure the intensive task isn't just... being intensive, and using up most of the system resources (so the UI thread also slows down)?

Comment: My crystal ball said: "1) screws it up, too many messages.  The UI thread is completely bogged down and doesn't get around to doing its normal duties anymore."  Prompting it for more didn't produce anything but a faint throbbing glow.  I think it's tired.  Or it's Friday.

Comment: Hans, I've disabled receiving messages while debugging and the prob still occurs.

Comment: Jon & Peachykeen, task manager still shows ~ 95% idle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reduce your thread's priority. I'm assuming though this happens to your system and not just the program. If it happens in your program, are you certain nothing else is going on in your main app thread and that its actually running on a separate thread?

Try reducing the thread's priority - see:
[Programmatically limit CPU Usage of a Thread running inside a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482592/programmatically-limit-cpu-usage-of-a-thread-running-inside-a-service)

Comment: The system isn't affected at all it seems.  I did lower the thread priority to below normal but same thing.  A strange effect seems that I can move around the UI and close the window without any problems but I can't press any buttons.

Comment: Fake your c call to some other .net method that spins the CPU maybe a while loop looking for a true Val. See if it is an oddity with the interop.

Comment: I faked it to a .NET method instead and it worked fine.  You might be right that it's an oddity with the interop.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try a general answer, since you haven't specified which C# UI technology you're using (WPF or Winforms), and haven't given any example of your UI code:
I think you'd better off keep your C code as a simple utility library, without trying to do any threading stuff there, and Let the C# code manage the background thread. .Net UI has many threading techniques to keep the UI responsive while doing some long tasks in the background, e.g.: `Backgroundworker`, `Dispatcher.Invoke`, `Control.Invoke` etc... (take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017338/looking-for-some-ui-thread-and-working-thread-tutorials) for example).

Comment: Windows.Forms.  But I've already tried leaving the C dll to perform simple utilities while allowing C# to manage the threads for me.  The UI code itself is trivial.  It's just a button that starts and stops the process, which essentially calls task_ToggleTask().

Comment: So why wouldn't it call task_Calculate inside BeginInvoke of the form?

Comment: It can and did. The same problem occurred. I tested it again just now in case you have any doubts.  I already have a pure C version written.  I'll just convert it to a library and then let C manage the UI and the threading so .NET doesn't have to get involved until the final results are needed.

Comment: Can you please add your C# code? There should be something wrong somewhere, because the simple scenario would work. There's probably some twist in your code that made it a special case, and caused you to post this question :-)